# Fitting nls() in r when some x values equal zero

Tags: r, nls

Is it possible to calculate a NLS regression when you have `x = 0` ?

```
mydf <- structure(list(x = c(0, 25.8, 51.6, 77.4, 103.2, 129, 154.8, 
                             180.6, 206.4, 232.2, 258), y = c(1, 0.04347826, 0.021739129, 
                                                              0.013888888, 0.010869564, 0.008620688, 0.007299269, 0.006289307, 
                                                              0.005405404, 0.004830917, 0.004329003)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                           -11L))

lmod <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x), data = mydf)

a_start <- exp(lmod$coefficients[[1]])
b_start <- lmod$coefficients[[2]]

nlmod <- nls(y ~ a*x^b, data = mydf, 
             start = list(a = a_start,
                          b = b_start))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = y~a*x^b, 
              method.args = list(start = c(a = a_start,b = b_start)),
              se=FALSE)
```

This produces the following errors because of `log(0)`.

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

Obviously it works when I filter by `x>0` but `y` is limited to`1` as it's a proportion and when using `x>0` only we get values where `y>1`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pmax(x, 1)` in place of `x` and simplify slightly by using nls for the starting values as well:

```
fm0 <- nls(log(y) ~ log(a * pmax(x, 1)^b), mydf, start = list(a = 1, b = 1))
fm1 <- nls(y ~ a * pmax(x, 1)^b, mydf, start = coef(fm0))
```

### Update

Have made a number of improvements.

Comment: Unfortunately ```max(predict(fm1)) = 1.311985``` and ```y``` is a proportion so should only have a max of 1.

Comment: Not clear what you have done but using fm1 from the answer (note that I made some improvements) gives `max(fitted(fm1))` equal to 1 (modulo floating point approx).  Also, if you don't mind changing the model try  `nls(y ~ 1 / (1 + b*x^c), mydf, start = c(b = 1, c = 1))`

Comment: I'd gone back to the full dataset. That new model did the trick, thanks. I'm a bit new to nls model fitting - any tips or links to help with deciding on the best model formula?

Comment: Hard to say. Have a look through the `nls` answers on SO.